# ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to filter the results of a scan of a DynamoDB table using a FilterExpression in my query. I'm using a Lambda function deployed on API Gateway on AWS.

**Function Querying the Endpoint**

```
// Scan the table for entries and use data to populate HTML table.
async function scanTable(){
  
    var query = {
        TableName: "bookings",
        ProjectionExpression: "id, username, start_booking, end_booking",
        FilterExpression: "username = :u",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {":u":"human@gmail.com"}
    };

    try{      
        const response = await axios({ method: 'get', url: `${url}/bookings`, params: query });    
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

**Lambda Function**

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');


exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({convertEmptyValues: true});

    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;

    const params = (event.queryStringParameters);
    // console.log(params);
    
    try{
        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
        statusCode = 200;
    }catch(err){
        responseBody = `Unable to get the bookings: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403;
    }
    
    console.log("Response Body: " + responseBody);

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: responseBody
    };
    
    

    return response;
}
```

The complete error I receive is

`ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "11"`

where the key value at the end of the error (key:"11") changes somewhat dependent on the value assigned in ExpressionAttributeValues. I've tried to follow the FilterExpression example in the [DynamoDB Docs for the scan function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) to no avail. Here is another [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan).

[Here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=870941&#870941) is a similar question from the AWS forums.

Answer (score 0):

I  think you should modify your ExpressionAttributeValues to:

```
var query = {
    TableName: "bookings",
    ProjectionExpression: "id, username, start_booking, end_booking",
    FilterExpression: "username = :u",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 'S': "human@gmail.com" }
};
```